# Deselect table cell when clicking away. Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I have the below table view but I want to be able to deselect the target cell when I click off to the side onto my view controller. I checked about using the deselect row at index path but not sure if theres a way to trigger that by clicking off to the side.

[image]]

Comment: This answer should help you achieve that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25503413/4763963 Good luck!

Comment: Is there a version in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click off your table view, some event handler must be triggered in order for you to do a row deselection. So if the rest of your view controller is a static without user interaction, you can simply place a transparent `UIView` over the rest of your view controller and do deselect like this:

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.checkAction(sender:)))

self.YourTransparentView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

func checkAction(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need step 1. Simply ask the table view what the currently selected indexPath is. No need to track it yourself.